# Manipulating a data frame with category and frequency (apriori style) in frequency: category1; category2.. format

Tags: r

I have to write the data in the following format: support:category_1;category_2;category_3;..., where each line corresponds to a category data set. Where support is frequency and category ex. Armenian.

```
dat<-read.csv("https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_9b0d0ff87935997de01d221fd74bae90_categories.txt?Expires=1486252800&Signature=P~Q4jU6ufMqC12Usn0n6feJPZdDMERgOVD5WNflxwnbAxREulmhdpo2~YGO7yK5STLrp1KuQeq-06q4IVsCIz3jTxe-u-kL6sh-ZcgYWFC~hUh3zzjL0x6fEKJ5rtYyR8ztzYz9utGAkvhBrNmhIYWB7r36PNvkfl8lV36qfr50_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A")

dat[10, ]
out<-strsplit(as.character(dat[1:79137, ]), ';')
result<-unlist(out)
length(result)
table(result)
interm_result<-as.data.frame((table(result)))
order_result<-interm_result[order(interm_result$Freq, interm_result$result)]
order_result looks like bellow:
                              result  Freq
39                          Armenian     1
42                   Art Restoration     1
45                         Art Tours     1
49        Assisted Living Facilities     1
64                          Backshop     1
90                         Beer Hall     1
96                      Bike Sharing     1
153                       Carpenters     1
158                          Castles     1
168             Childbirth Education     1
169                    Childproofing     1
175                           Choirs     1
186               College Counseling     1
195                Community Gardens     1
198                    Concept Shops     1
233             Debt Relief Services     1
244                 Dialysis Clinics     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## read file

dat<- read.csv("https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_9b0d0ff87935997de01d221fd74bae90_categories.txt?Expires=1486252800&Signature=P~Q4jU6ufMqC12Usn0n6feJPZdDMERgOVD5WNflxwnbAxREulmhdpo2~YGO7yK5STLrp1KuQeq-06q4IVsCIz3jTxe-u-kL6sh-ZcgYWFC~hUh3zzjL0x6fEKJ5rtYyR8ztzYz9utGAkvhBrNmhIYWB7r36PNvkfl8lV36qfr50_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A")

dat[10, ]

Create function to manipulate data
## create a function that removes the separator 
out<-strsplit(as.character(dat[1:79137, ]), ';')

## as there are multiple elements in a line, write each element on a new line
result<-unlist(out)

## list length
length(result)

## find the frequency of each element
table(result)
interm_result<-as.data.frame((table(result)))

##write the data in final format
final<-data.frame(interm_result$Freq, sep=':', interm_result$result)

## write the data to a file
fileConn<- file("DataMining.txt")
write.table(final, fileConn)
close(fileConn)

Part 2: organize data support:category_1, category_2,…
## order_result<-interm_result[order(interm_result$Freq, interm_result$result)]
## indi<-unique(order_result$Freq)

##Arrange list by frequency
new_arr<-split(interm_result$result, interm_result$Freq, drop=FALSE)

## Transform in character strings 
new_arr[]<- lapply(new_arr, as.character)

## Number of elements with the same frequency
t_result<-table(order_result$Freq)

## Change header names
names(d_result)[1]<-paste("Freq")
names(d_result)[2]<-paste("Category")

## Change class of order_result
d_result[]<-lapply(d_result, as.character)

## Sort elements by frequency
Result<-aggregate(d_result.Category ~ d_result.Freq, d_result, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ";"))

## Change column names to an easier form
names(Data_result)[3]<-paste("Freq")
names(Data_result)[3]<-paste("Category")
names(Data_result)[2]<-paste(" ")

## Final data frame
Data_result<-data.frame(Result$d_result.Freq, sep=":", Result$d_result.Category)
```